# Actual stereo sound with bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a bluetooth headset (Logitech UE9000), I always found the sound quality on OSX to be less than when connected to my android phone.

Further investigation leads me to believe that there is no stereo sound being outputted. A simple youtube stereo test (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAOQWSmkofA) has the result of left or right channel to be outputted simultaneously to both earspeakers.

This is not an quality issue, the sound is clear, as such, the advise which is littered everywhere on the web to up the quality by doing some command line magic is not helping:

```
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Apple Bitpool Min (editable)" 200
```

By alt-clicking on the bluetooth icon I can see that my active codec is "AptX" which should be the correct codec for high quality.

Do others have successfully connected their headsets with real stereo/separate channel audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if "Play stereo as mono" is selected in Accessibility->audio is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this issue? I found this set of changes fixes the output, though I'm still having tinny input quality over bluetooth:

```
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Apple Bitpool Max (editable)" 120
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Apple Bitpool Min (editable)" 80
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Apple Initial Bitpool (editable)" 120
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Apple Initial Bitpool Min (editable)" 80
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Negotiated Bitpool" 100
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Negotiated Bitpool Max" 120
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Negotiated Bitpool Min" 80
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Stream - Flush Ring on Packet Drop (editable)" 30
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Stream - Max Outstanding Packets (editable)" 15
defaults write com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent "Stream Resume Delay" 0.75
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, still no real stereo

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution perse, but upgrading to 10.10, solved this for me.

Comment: Upgraded to El Capitan, Back to joint stereo unfortunately